# Autoplay video like facebook , Android

Tags: android, facebook, video

How to do an autoplay like facebook in a listview, only one video at a time, and pause it when it comes out of focus.

thank you very much.
I hope you can help me

Comment: anyone ? helpe please

Comment: Did you get any solution ? If any pls share it would be helpful for me. Me too looking hard for that.

Comment: That's right !, I could finally solve my problem. Use a textureView. I can leave you an example of how to implement it.
http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-playing-video

Next, it was only logical to apply, create an imaginary line in the center of the screen. when X and Y position of textureView you were in the range of that line, the video would be played.

Always use only one textureView, not to expose the phone memory. Create and destroy objects, remember that very well.

This is the project where the use
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gruporeforma.sm&hl=es

Comment: Hey, What id there are multiple videos in one raw of listview ? i.e. what if we have multiple videos in viewpager, viewpager inside listview ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is auto play video in list and recyclerview.

Implementing video playback in a scrolled list (ListView & RecyclerView) by Danylo Volokh

Here is the gradle dependency for the library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
}
```

Article [link](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429) and code [git link](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager)

**Demo**

[image]